# average aggregation in pandas groupby while considering unique values of a column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have te following dataframe:

```
df:
S0  S1  V1  V2  V3  V4
A   B   1   9   1   4
A   B   2   8   1   4
A   B   3   7   1   4
A   B   4   6   1   4
A   B   5   5   1   4
A   B   6   4   1   4
A   C   7   3   2   3
A   C   8   2   2   3
A   C   9   1   2   3
A   C   9   0   2   3
```

I am doing a groupby here to aggregate the values and get the below table:

```
df:
S0  S1  V1  V2  V3  V4
A   B   21  39   1   4
A   C   33   6   2   3
```

Column V1 and V2 are aggregated by sum whereas column V3 and V4 are taken average based on the unique values of column S1.

Groupby aggregation if used directly does not consider the column S1 for unique values. What can be the way forward for this?

Comment: Can you explain more `Groupby aggregation if used directly does not consider the column S1 for unique values. What can be the way forward for this?` ?

Answer (score 7):

I believe you need grouping by `S0` and `S1` with aggregate:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['S0','S1'], as_index=False)
         .agg({'V1':'sum','V2':'sum','V3':'mean','V4':'mean'}))
print (df1)
  S0 S1  V1  V2  V3  V4
0  A  B  21  39   1   4
1  A  C  33   6   2   3
```